# How to fill a field with random unique numbers in SQL2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which there is an **int field**. This field should be filled with random number and it should be unique. What is the best solution? Should I generate a random number and check if it exists in the table? By the way I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: What is the purpose of this field?

Comment: How your table INT field getting those unique random number?

Comment: Are you restricted to only using an int field and if you want to keep it as an int, can you set an identity on the column?

Comment: For your purpose, you need to set your (expected random number) column to be an IDENTITY.

Comment: unless you have specific requirements the best way is to have SQL server take care of setting the unique int values. The best way to do is (as suggested by others as well) to set identity on your column.

Comment: A random number is never guaranteed to be unique.  If you really need random numbers, you can get them [here](http://www.random.org/).

Comment: Please tell us why you need a random number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need it to be random? If you just need an unique integer value, use Identity. Check [this link](http://www.plus2net.com/asp-tutorial/sql-identity.php)

Edit:
For random number (BigInt) you may try this:

```
SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(5)) AS Bigint)) as UniqueNo
```

Found it in [here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2007/12/generate-unique-number-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a very good solution. Is there any way to generate a shorter number? The user should use this number in many pages of my application. So he should remind this number. Any way your solution is awesome.

Comment: Note that this method is not suitable if you need your random numbers to be reasonably unpredictable (please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/23/10309199.aspx). If predictability isn't a problem, why use random numbers at all, a simple identity column might do.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw This is true, but a truly random number is not guaranteed to be unique. My solution gives you random-like unique number. I can't think of any other way to achieve this.

Comment: @Adam My comment was really addressed at the original questioner, and anybody looking at this in the future. However, casting to a `varbinary(5)` truncates the `uniqueidentifier` from 16 to 5 bytes with two consequences: (1) the degree to which this 5 byte value is unique will be far less than that of a full GUID, which is not guaranteed 100% unique in the first place; (2) The 5 byte value will be even less random than a full GUID, which, again, is not designed to be random even in its complete form.

Answer (score 0):

Use GUID:

```
public string GetRandomGUID(int length)
{
  // Get the GUID
  string guidResult = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

  // Remove the hyphens
  guidResult = guidResult.Replace("-", string.Empty);

  // Make sure length is valid
  if (length <= 0 || length > guidResult.Length)
    throw new ArgumentException("Length must be between 1 and " + guidResult.Length);

  // Return the first length bytes
  return guidResult.Substring(0, length);
}
```

Comment: How does that help generate a random integer? Or are you suggesting changing the field type?

Comment: If you are stuck with needing to use an int field and cant set it as an identity in the database, then you could create a stored proc which gets the max number in the column and increments it.

Comment: @angusf - I know what a GUID is thanks. I was just pointing out this answer doesn't address the question. Might be a perfectly reasonable end solution depending on what the column is actually for though.

Comment: @MartinSmith if its int field making it Identity column in SQL SERVER would be better option as suggested by augusf

Comment: GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random. Please see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/23/10309199.aspx.

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry martin, I edited comment after re-reading your first comment.

Comment: It should be an int number and random

Answer (score 0):

From `Front End` using `C#`

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") //Replaces all - will Empty values. 
                               Final value will be numeric
```

From Database

```
newid()
```

---

Both these techniques will give you unique results.

Comment: A GUID is not random: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three.aspx

Comment: yes but how unique is an integer? The requirements stated they should be random too.

Comment: @Erno - As per my knowledge GUID will give a random as well as UNIQUE value.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx to generate the random number and then query the database to check if the value exists. You should be able to determine it by selecting rows where 'int field' = 'random number' and checking whether the @@rowcount = 0.

Comment: How about performance? Don't you think this may be slow on large database?

Comment: @Adam It could be, but at some stage (without using an identity) you will have to check to see whether the value already exists in the column. Personally I would be using a GUID or identity.